# undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have this table that is a has many through relationship.

```
create_table "usergroups", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
  t.bigint "user_id"
  t.bigint "group_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["group_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_group_id"
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_usergroups_on_user_id"
end
```

To destroy a record in this table I have come up with the following method to do so.

```
def remove
  @usergroup = Usergroup.where('user_id = ?', params[:user_id]).where('group_id = ?', params[:group_id]).first.destroy
  redirect_to groups_path
end
```

This is a table so I make sure to get the group_id and the user_id for each row to delete the correct row the user selects.

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', { controller: "groups", action: "remove" },
    group_id: @group.id, user_id: user.id, data: 
    { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

If I look at the source code I can see that each row is getting the corresponding user_id and group_id.

```
<a group_id="6" user_id="2" data-confirm="Are you sure?" href="/groups/remove/6">Remove</a>
```

At the moment, when I try to delete this I am getting the following error.

```
undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass
```

I am aware that, from the error message, it is not finding anything with that information in it. I am getting this in the error message as well.

> Request
>
> Parameters:
>
> {"id"=>"6"}

For the group I am trying to delete the group_id is 6 however in the parameters it is clearly saying the 'id' is 6. Perhaps this is a routing issue? This is the current route I have setup to delete records.

```
get 'groups/remove/:id', to: 'groups#remove'
```

If this is a routing issue, what do I need to fix in order for this to delete records successfully? Can anybody help me out? Rails routing is confusing to me.

Comment: Those values you're passing are just being used as attributes for the anchor tag, hence the `group_id="6" user_id="2"`, and the only one parameter is the id recognized in the route `/groups/remove/6`, that's why the query doesn't get any results, and no first nor destroy methods are availables. Try instead using a path and passing the ids, like `user_groups_path(group_id: @group.id, user_id: user.id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the respective ids within the curly braces:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', 
  { controller: 'groups', action: 'remove', group_id: @group.id, user_id: user.id },
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

If you'd setted a route, that'd be less code:

```
<%= link_to 'Remove', 
  groups_path(group_id: @group.id, user_id: user.id),
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

Comment: What would the correct route be if I were to add one? I would like to use as little code as possible. That worked by the way.

Comment: Have you defined a resources routes for groups?, id you didn't then you can just create a new route for the destroy method, like `delete '/groups/:id', to: 'groups#remove', as: :destroy_group`, then reference that route as `destroy_group_path(group_id: @group, user_id: user)`. Note just passing the object Rails infers the id attribute.